# Angularjs passing data to Asp.Net Web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-services

I am trying to import textfile from angularjs ui and insert the data to database. I am able to import file and read the content of file. I am also able to Insert the data to database with webapi. But I got blocked while passing data from UI to web api. I am not sure what was the issue in this context. What mistake I did in this code?

UI CODE

```
<div>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button ng-click="importMyData()">Import Configuration</button>
</div>

<div>
    {{fileContent}}
</div>
```

Angular controller code

```
  $scope.importMyData = function () {
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function (e) {
        var binary = "";
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        var length = bytes.byteLength;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }

        $scope.fileContent = (binary).toString();
        importData($scope.fileContent);

    }
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}

function importData(fileContent) {      
    importConfigurationService.get({MyImportedData: fileContent}).$promise
       .then(function (data) {
           alert(data);
       });
}
```

Angular Service code

```
app.factory('importMyDataService', ['$resource', 'settings', function ($resource, settings) {
    return $resource(settings.BaseSetting + '/api/ImportMyData');
}]);
```

Web Api Code

```
[Route("ImportMyData")]
    [HttpGet]
    public int ImportConfiguration(string MyImportedData)
    {
       string importedData = MyImportedData;
   //Code to save imported data to db here

       return importStatus;
    }
```

Comment: what do you have on the angular side at the moment?

Comment: Its in the Jsfiddle.(This)

Comment: @Chandana Please include the relevant code snippets within the question. JSFiddle and similar are often helpful, but should not be the sole copy.

Comment: You've got to go deeper than "What mistake did I make in this code?"  What do you mean by "I got blocked passing data from UI to Web API?"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a MultipartMemoryStreamProvider

```
 public class UploadingController : ApiController
{
    public void Post()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("c:/uploads/");
            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                });
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
    }
}
```

The following articles should steer you in the right direction.

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

http://chris.59north.com/post/Uploading-files-using-ASPNET-Web-Api

https://www.briankeating.net/post/Angularjs-NET-File-Upload